# Adding a TextView to a ListView

Tags: android, view, android-listview, textview, xamarin

In `Xamarin`

I want to add a simple TextView to a ListVIew, yet am not sure of the correct code.

Here is my current code:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

    ListView listView = new ListView(this.ApplicationContext);
    TextView textView = new TextView (this.ApplicationContext);
    textView.Text = "Example text";
    View view = new View (this.ApplicationContext);
}
```

Can I please have some help?

**EDIT**

Here is my code:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    ListView lst = (ListView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.listView);

    // create the ArrayList to store the titles of nodes
    List<String> listItems = new List<String>();
    listItems.Add ("Test 1");
    listItems.Add ("Test 2");

    ArrayAdapter ad = new ArrayAdapter(this.ApplicationContext, Resource.Layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);

    // give adapter to ListView UI element to render
    lst.SetAdapter(ad);

    }
```

I am getting this error:

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

May I please have some help with this code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to create a custom adapter or use simpleAdapter or ArrayAdapter to show text in ListView.

Comment: At what position of ListView you want to add this TextView?

Comment: At the first position.

Answer (score 1):

If its a simple textView List then use this:

```
ListView lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // create the ArrayList to store the titles of nodes
        ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then add all text in ArrayList listItems 
Then use below method

```
ArrayAdapter ad = new ArrayAdapter(ListActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);

        // give adapter to ListView UI element to render
        lst.setAdapter(ad);
```

XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @user22707 why its Add it should be add. in your edit

Comment: Are you talking about adding the string items to a List?

Comment: is it giving you NullPointerException @user22707 ??

Comment: I am getting a NullReferenceException

Comment: @user22707 which line paste here?

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/category/list-view/) link.You can use that, as per your requirement
[type2](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show some strings in the ListView:

Declare the following variables:

```
private ArrayList<String> _listEntrys = new ArrayList<String>();    // String-ArrayList for storing the itmes that should be shown in the list
private ArrayAdapter<String> _arrayAdapter;                     // Arrayadapter to fill your list
```

Your OnCreate should then look something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Create ListView
    ListView listView = new ListView(this.ApplicationContext);

    // Set Array-Adapter
    _arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, _listEntrys);
    listview.setAdapter(m_ArrayAdapter);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    // Add here your desired List-Items
    _listEntrys.add("your string");

    _arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   // Call this everytime you change the values in the ArrayList to refresh the view

}
```